# Serialize object to XML WITHIN a parent element

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, serialization

I've got a WPF C# program and at one point I need to serialize objects to XML. In other places, I've been using this:

```
TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(xmlFilePath);
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MYOBJECT_TYPE));

try
{
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, MYOBJECT);

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Exception occured while writing to Xml" + ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    writer.Close();
}
```

This is fantastic, but this means I have to have a different XML file for every object I want to serialize. How do I use this method (with the least amount of modifications) to serialize the object to the XML **WITHIN a parent element**? That way, when I want to deserialize the object later, I can just find the element that I want, and deserialize everything within that element.

*As requested, here is `CreateDefaultXml();`:*

```
static void CreateDefaultXml()
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml("<StoredObjects></StoredObjects>");
    XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
    try
    {
        doc.Save(xmlFilePath);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception occured while creating Xml" + ex.InnerException);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Currently, this is what I've got (but it throws an exception `There was an error generating the XML document.`)

```
if (!File.Exists(xmlFilePath))
    CreateDefaultXml();

XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xmlFilePath);
var element = doc.Descendants("Object").Where(x => x.Attribute("Name").Value.Equals("objectName")).SingleOrDefault();

if (element == null)
{
    element = new XElement("Object", new XAttribute("Name", objectName));
    doc.Element("StoredObjects").Add(element);
}

XmlWriter writer = element.CreateWriter();
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MYOBJECT_TYPE));

try
{
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, MYOBJECT);

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Exception occured while writing to Xml: " + ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    writer.Close();
    doc.Save(xmlFilePath);
}
```

Comment: 1) What is `shape`?  In the line `shape.CreateWriter();` it is undefined.  2) Can you share `CreateDefaultXml();`?

Comment: @dbc Sorry. I have updated the question

Comment: I changed the `MessageBox.Show` to show `ex.InnerException` and get `System.InvalidOperationException: WriteStartDocument cannot be called on writers created with ConformanceLevel.Fragment.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to serialize directly to some nested `XElement` inside an `XDocument` using `XmlSerializer`.  Unfortunately, it seems that, when serializing directly to a LINQ-to-XML `XElement` using `XmlSerializer` together with [`XContainer.CreateWriter()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.createwriter.aspx), it is actually necessary to serialize to an empty `XDocument` thereby creating its root element.  (I am not sure why this restriction exists, but it does.)  Since this doesn't meet your needs, it is easy to serialize to a *temporary* `XDocument`, remove its root node, then add that node to your overall element hierarchy.

Also, when adding an object to your database using an `objectName` that already has XML data stored, you need to remove the old data.

I refactored your code into extension methods to accomplish this:

```
public static class XmlExtensions
{
    public static T Deserialize<T>(this XContainer element, XmlSerializer serializer = null)
    {
        using (var reader = element.CreateReader())
        {
            object result = (serializer ?? new XmlSerializer(typeof(T))).Deserialize(reader);
            if (result is T)
                return (T)result;
        }
        return default(T);
    }

    public static XElement SerializeToXElement<T>(this T obj, XmlSerializer serializer = null)
    {
        var doc = new XDocument();
        using (var writer = doc.CreateWriter())
            (serializer ?? new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType())).Serialize(writer, obj);
        var element = doc.Root;
        if (element != null)
            element.Remove();
        return element;
    }

    public static XName ContainerElementName { get { return (XName)"Object"; } }

    public static XName ContainerAttributeName { get { return (XName)"Name"; } }

    public static XElement SetItem<T>(this XDocument doc, string attributeValue, T obj)
    {
        return doc.SetItem(ContainerElementName, ContainerAttributeName, attributeValue, obj);
    }

    static XElement SetItem<T>(this XDocument doc, XName containerElementName, XName containerAttributeName, string attributeValue, T obj)
    {
        if (doc == null || containerElementName == null || containerAttributeName == null || attributeValue == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (doc.Root == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("doc.Root == null");
        var container = doc.Root.Elements(containerElementName).Where(e => (string)e.Attribute(containerAttributeName) == attributeValue).SingleOrDefault();
        if (container == null)
        {
            container = new XElement(containerElementName, new XAttribute(containerAttributeName, attributeValue));
            doc.Root.Add(container);
        }
        else
        {
            // Remove old content.
            container.RemoveNodes();
        }

        var element = obj.SerializeToXElement();
        container.Add(element);
        return element;
    }

    public static T GetItem<T>(this XDocument doc, string attributeValue)
    {
        return doc.GetItem<T>(ContainerElementName, ContainerAttributeName, attributeValue);
    }

    static T GetItem<T>(this XDocument doc, XName containerElementName, XName containerAttributeName, string attributeValue)
    {
        if (doc == null || containerElementName == null || containerAttributeName == null || attributeValue == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (doc.Root == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("doc.Root == null");
        var container = doc.Root.Elements(containerElementName).Where(e => (string)e.Attribute(containerAttributeName) == attributeValue).SingleOrDefault();
        if (container == null)
            return default(T);
        var element = container.Elements().SingleOrDefault();
        if (element == null)
            return default(T);
        return element.Deserialize<T>();
    }

    public static XDocument CreateDefaultXDocument()
    {
        var xml = @"<StoredObjects></StoredObjects>";
        return XDocument.Parse(xml);
    }
}
```

Now you can do

```
doc.AddItem(MYOBJECT, objectName);
```

And later

```
var MYOBJECT2 = doc.GetItem<MYOBJECT_TYPE>(objectName);
```

Example [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KkQT5C).