# How To Serialize/Deserialize An Object To/From A Specified XML Node?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I'm trying to serialize an object to and from an XML settings file using *XmlSerializer* and *XmlWriter/XMLReader*.

In its simplest form this is fairly trivial:

```
XmlSerializer oSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(mySettings), new XmlRootAttribute("Settings"));
    using (XmlWriter oXmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(myFilePath) 
        oSerializer.Serialize(oXmlWriter, mySettings);
```

and

```
XmlSerializer oSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(mySettings), new XmlRootAttribute("Settings"));
    using (XmlReader oXmlReader = XmlReader.Create(myFilePath)
        oSerializer.Serialize(oXmlWriter, mySettings);
```

produces and reads (simplified example):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Settings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Token>NC05MWY4NmJkOGRl</Token>
  <TokenExpiry>2017-11-01</TokenExpiry>
  <TokenType>bearer</TokenType>
</Settings>
```

However, I’m trying to save (and read) various versions of the (same) object in different nodes, something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Settings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ThisSetting>
    <Token>NC05MWY4NmJkOGRl</Token>
    <TokenExpiry>2017-11-01</TokenExpiry>
    <TokenType>bearer</TokenType>
  </ThisSetting>
  <ThatSetting>
    <Token>eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1Qi</Token>
    <TokenExpiry>2017-11-05</TokenExpiry>
    <TokenType>token</TokenType>
  </ThatSetting>
</Settings>
```

**NOTE**: As the same class of object is being written, the XML structure is identical between nodes.

I can manually describe *ThisSetting* and *ThatSetting*; they aren't part of the object definition. And I need to handle the situation where the file doesn't initially exist, or if there is only, say, a *ThatSetting* when I go to save a *ThisSetting* (the order in the file is irrelevant), so the ability to add nodes is required. (I could simply have multiple files, I guess, but that seems pretty untidy.)

Can anyone provide a simple and clean way of doing this? Obviously, I can manually parse the file for writing and reading, but that seems like it shouldn't be necessary. And I could wrap the object to provide *ThisSetting* and *ThatSetting* as enclosing properties, but *ThisSetting* and *ThatSetting* are dynamic according to product names which can vary in name and number and may change over time.

Ideas? Have I missed something obvious?

Comment: Shouldn't the Opening and Closing Tags be written similar: `<Token></AccessToken>`?

Comment: Do you want to save into a File(XML) or a Database?

Comment: @Nikolaus Typo, sorry. Fixed. To a file, eg settings.xml, as per post.

Comment: Do Settings always have the same structure?

Comment: @Nikolaus Yes, as per example and additional note in post.

Comment: You could load your XML into an `XDocument` (or create one if the file does not exist yet) and then serialize directly to some nested element by following the instructions from [Serialize object to XML WITHIN a parent element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37443397/3744182).

Comment: Or, if you're looking for a trick to add a node to an XML file without loading the entire file, see [Fastest way to add new node to end of an xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/849043/3744182) for some possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Easy to do with xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XElement settings = doc.Root;

            List<XElement> children = settings.Elements().ToList();

            settings.Descendants().Remove();

            settings.Add(new XElement("ThisSettings", children));
        }
    }
}
```